# Python opencv detect tip of the dial

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a question regarding how to find the tip of the dial in the image below.

[image]

Here are some attempts I have made:

1. Get red color from the image and do Hough transformation. The outcome is not pleasant because of the light effect on the dial, causing a big area of shadow to disturb the process of Hough transformation. (as shown in the image 2)

[image]

2. Canny edge detection. But the effect is similar.

Would like to hear for some advice on how to deal with this case.

Comment: same as always. find circle. polar transform. sample one row corresponding to one circle of pixels, result is 1D data. needle will be apparent in the 1D data.

Comment: Canny is absolutely useless here. it's also a newbie trap. -- Hough will not be able to find that dial/circle because the image is overexposed and the dial's recessed face is indistinguishable from the rest of the meter's face. -- applying Hough to only the needle makes no sense at all.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks Chris for your help! Can you explain a bit more on 'sample one row corresponding to one circle of pixels' please? Appreciate it!

Comment: behold [these pictures in `warpPolar`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga49481ab24fdaa0ffa4d3e63d14c0d5e4). one *row/column* (rectangular region) in the output corresponds to a *ring* in the input.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe binarizing the green component can help...

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response! Can you explain a bit more on what is the reason behind such operation? Appreciate it.

Comment: @XuanyuanZhang: the tip is red !